# Java Threading - Things to be aware of?

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

In my application I have the `MainThread` and I have a `SeperateThread`

I have the threads working almost to perfection. The only problem is I can't shut the `SeperateThread` down.

```
public void run()
{
    isRunning = true;
    while(isRunning)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Running...");
        long currentTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    }
}

public void StopThread()
{
    isRunning = false;
}

seperateThread.StopThread();
```

Then in the Thread I have a method that just turns the `volatile boolean isRunning` off. Even though I step through in the debugger noting that the thread switches the boolean to off.

- What would cause this type of problem?
- Is this the cleanest way to shut a thread down?
- Any other steps in shutting down a thread?
- Are their any setbacks in Androids multi-threading?

Comment: What is telling you that the SeparateThread is still running?

Comment: LogCat - I put a Log msg in the while

Comment: Is it possible that your thread is stuck somewhere in the loop?

Comment: Add your full code please. Specially the thread section. I'm just seeing a while loop running infinitely.

Comment: you might want to post your method that change isRunning to false

Comment: I didn't think the full code was necessary, more like overwhelming. Anyways I just call seperateThread.StopThread(); The question is more general than anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to be using the new concurrency package stuff for this, and grab a copy of [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601), and learn more about this. Threads are deceptively simple.

Why your code isn't working probably has to do with you not setting isRunning to false the way you expect. However, the java.util.concurrency package does this for you anyway.

In your case you should look at the Executor framework. So your code could look something like this:

```
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);//A field somewhere
    //Start your thread
    exec.submit(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!exec.isShutdown()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Running...");
                //Do stuff
            }
        }
    });
    //when done
    exec.shutdown();
```

---

Thinking about this overnight, this might be a better way:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    exec.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           //Do stuff
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    //when done
    exec.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thank you I'll look into this! What are the disadvantages vs the advantages of using this over java threads?

Comment: The direct usage of the Thread class is basically low level programming, which should be avoided. See here: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/concurrency/ch10lev1sec3

Comment: Thanks for the help your edit looks very interesting, I could definitely use that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
isRunning = true;
while(isRunning)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Running...");
    ...//Do something
}
```

Do you have a break in your while loop? Or are you setting isRunning = false, somewhere else?

Comment: I don't break out of the loop I call a method StopThread which turns isRunning to false